# sessionStorage onclick set value

Tags: javascript, html

I have 4 divs, and depending on what the user clicks I want to set a variable on each of them, which I then want to save using sessionStorage.

```
<div id="1" onClick="sessionStorage.id=1">Select Me as 1</div>
<div id="2" onClick="sessionStorage.id=2">Select Me as 2</div>
<div id="3" onClick="sessionStorage.id=3">Select Me as 3</div>
<div id="4" onClick="sessionStorage.id=4">Select Me as 4</div>
```

Then on the `<head></head>` area I've added:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("id", "");
sessionStorage.getItem("id");
alert(id);
```

My problem is that the values are not changing and the `onclick` doesn't see to be storing the new values.

How can I do this right?

Comment: why do you setItem before getItem

Comment: ID's [can't start with numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html), FWIW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this demo:

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ufugan/1/)

```
  <div id="1" onClick="sessionStorage.id=1">Select Me as 1</div>
  <div id="2" onClick="sessionStorage.id=2">Select Me as 2</div>
  <div id="3" onClick="sessionStorage.id=3">Select Me as 3</div>
  <div id="4" onClick="sessionStorage.id=4">Select Me as 4</div>
  <button onclick="alert(sessionStorage.getItem('id'))">Check Session Value</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess what you want to do is:

```
<div id="1" onClick="sessionStorage.setItem('id', '1')">Select Me 1</div>
<div id="2" onClick="sessionStorage.setItem('id', '2')">Select Me 1</div>
<div id="3" onClick="sessionStorage.setItem('id', '3')">Select Me 1</div>
<div id="4" onClick="sessionStorage.setItem('id', '4')">Select Me 1</div>

<button onClick="alert(sessionStorage.getItem('id'))">click to alert</button>
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wGgzC/)

Answer (score 2):

Your html to set the values is fine, but I have no idea why use are using `setItem()` before `getItem()` as that will clear out the values.  All you need in your head to alert the value of `id` is below:

```
var id = sessionStorage.getItem("id");
alert(id);
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/da5jC/1/)

*(just re rerun the fiddle to see the result of the click)*